# Не срабатывает будильник при заблокированном экране

Tags: java, android

В манифесте разрешения даны

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
 <activity android:name=".alarmclock.AlarmAlert" android:label="@string/alert_title"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true"
        android:taskAffinity=":AlarmAlert"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|navigation" />
```

активити

```
 import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.KeyguardManager;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.os.PowerManager;
    import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import com.gufa.myalarm2.R;
    import com.gufa.myalarm2.hardware.ShakeListener;
```

public class AlarmAlert extends Activity implements Alarms.AlarmSettings {

```
private static final int SNOOZE_MINUTES = 10;
private static final int UNKNOWN = 0;
private static final int SNOOZE = 1;
private static final int DISMISS = 2;
private static final int KILLED = 3;
private KeyguardManager mKeyguardManager;
private KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock mKeyguardLock;
private Button mSnoozeButton;
private int mState = UNKNOWN;
private AlarmKlaxon mKlaxon;
private int mAlarmId;
private AlarmPreference mAlarmPref;
private String mLabel;
private ShakeListener mShakeListener;
private int mSnooze;
private int mDuration;
private int mCaptchaSnooze, mCaptchaDismiss;
private boolean mCaptchaShown = false;
private boolean mCaptchaDone = false;
private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

public static final String DEBUG_TAG = AlarmReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    AlarmAlertWakeLock.acquire(this);
    Log.v("AlarmAlert.onCreate()");
    setWindowSettings();
    releaseWakeLock();
    acquireWakeLock();

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
    lp.token = null;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

    mKeyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    mAlarmId = i.getIntExtra(Alarms.ID, -1);

    Alarms.getAlarm(getContentResolver(), this, mAlarmId);

    mKlaxon = new AlarmKlaxon();
    mKlaxon.postPlay(this, mAlarmId);
    setTitleFromIntent(i);

    Alarms.disableSnoozeAlert(AlarmAlert.this);
    Alarms.disableAlert(AlarmAlert.this, mAlarmId);
    Alarms.setNextAlert(this);

    mKlaxon.setKillerCallback(new AlarmKlaxon.KillerCallback() {
        public void onKilled() {
            if (Log.LOGV) Log.v("onKilled()");
            updateSilencedText();

               mSnoozeButton.setEnabled(false);

            dismiss();
            mState = KILLED;
        }
    });

    updateLayout();

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(AlarmClock.PREFERENCES, 0);
    if (settings.getBoolean(AlarmClock.PREF_SHAKE_SNOOZE, true)) {
        mShakeListener = new ShakeListener(this);
        mShakeListener.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeListener.OnShakeListener() {
            public void onShake() {
                snooze();
                if (mCaptchaSnooze == 0)
                    finish();
            }
        });
    }
}

private void setTitleFromIntent(Intent i) {
    mLabel = i.getStringExtra(Alarms.LABEL);
    if (mLabel == null || mLabel.length() == 0) {
        mLabel = getString(R.string.default_label);
    }
    setTitle(mLabel);
}
private void setWindowSettings()
{
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    } else
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
    }}

public void acquireWakeLock()
{
   PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE
            | PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "alarming_wakelock");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
}

public void releaseWakeLock()
{
          if (mWakeLock != null)
    {
        if (mWakeLock.isHeld())
        {
            mWakeLock.release();
            mWakeLock = null;
        }
    }
}

private void updateSilencedText() {
    TextView silenced = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.silencedText);
    silenced.setText(getString(R.string.alarm_alert_alert_silenced,
            mDuration / 1000*60));
    silenced.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void updateLayout() {
    setContentView(R.layout.alarm_alert);

    AlarmAlertWakeLock.acquire(this);
    LayoutInflater mFactory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    SharedPreferences settings =
            getSharedPreferences(AlarmClock.PREFERENCES, 0);
    int face = settings.getInt(AlarmClock.PREF_CLOCK_FACE, 0);
    if (face < 0 || face >= AlarmClock.CLOCKS.length) {
        face = 0;
    }
    View clockLayout =
            (View) mFactory.inflate(AlarmClock.CLOCKS[face], null);
    ViewGroup clockView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.clockView);
    clockView.addView(clockLayout);
    if (clockLayout instanceof DigitalClock) {
        ((DigitalClock) clockLayout).setAnimate();
    }

    mSnoozeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.snooze);
    if (mSnooze > 0) {
        mSnoozeButton.requestFocus();
        mSnoozeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else { 
        mSnoozeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (mState == KILLED) {
        updateSilencedText();
        mSnoozeButton.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        mSnoozeButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                snooze();
                if (mCaptchaSnooze == 0)
                    finish();
            }
        });
    }

    findViewById(R.id.dismiss).setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dismiss();
                    if (mCaptchaDismiss == 0)
                        finish();
                }
            });
}

private void snooze() {
    if (mState != UNKNOWN) {
        return;
    }
    if (mSnooze == 0) { // snooze disabled for this alarm
        return;
    }
    if (mCaptchaSnooze != 0 && !mCaptchaDone) {
        show_captcha(mCaptchaSnooze, SNOOZE);
        return;
    }

    final long snoozeTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            + (1000 * 60 * mSnooze);
    final long nextAlarm =
            Alarms.calculateNextAlert(AlarmAlert.this).getAlert();
    String displayTime = null;
    if (nextAlarm < snoozeTime) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(nextAlarm);
        displayTime = getString(R.string.alarm_alert_snooze_not_set,
                Alarms.formatTime(AlarmAlert.this, c));
        mState = DISMISS;
    } else {
        Alarms.saveSnoozeAlert(AlarmAlert.this, mAlarmId, snoozeTime,
                mLabel);
        Alarms.setNextAlert(AlarmAlert.this);
        displayTime = getString(R.string.alarm_alert_snooze_set,
                mSnooze);
        mState = SNOOZE;
    }
    Log.v(displayTime);
     Toast.makeText(AlarmAlert.this, displayTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mKlaxon.stop(this, mState == SNOOZE);
    releaseLocks();
    finish();
}

private void dismiss() {
    if (mState != UNKNOWN) {
        return;
    }
    if (mCaptchaDismiss != 0 && !mCaptchaDone) {
        show_captcha(mCaptchaDismiss, DISMISS);
        return;
    }
    mState = DISMISS;
    mKlaxon.stop(this, false);
    releaseLocks();
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    AlarmAlertWakeLock.acquire(this);
    if (Log.LOGV) Log.v("AlarmAlert.OnNewIntent()");
    mState = UNKNOWN;
    mSnoozeButton.setEnabled(true);
    disableKeyguard();

    mAlarmId = intent.getIntExtra(Alarms.ID, -1);
    mKlaxon.postPlay(this, mAlarmId);

    setTitleFromIntent(intent);

    TextView silenced = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.silencedText);
    silenced.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Alarms.setNextAlert(this);
    setIntent(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (Log.LOGV) Log.v("AlarmAlert.onResume()");
    disableKeyguard();

    if (mShakeListener != null)
        mShakeListener.resume();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    AlarmAlertWakeLock.acquire(this);
    if (Log.LOGV) Log.v("AlarmAlert.onStop()");
    snooze();
    releaseLocks();

    if (mShakeListener != null)
        mShakeListener.pause();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
    updateLayout();
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    boolean up = event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP;
    boolean dismiss = false;
    switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL:
            break;
           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            dismiss = true;
                   default:
                        if (mState == UNKNOWN && up) {
                if (dismiss) {
                    dismiss();
                } else {
                    snooze();
                }
            }
            //mKlaxon.stop(this, false);
            //finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

private synchronized void enableKeyguard() {
    if (mKeyguardLock != null) {
        mKeyguardLock.reenableKeyguard();
        mKeyguardLock = null;
    }
}

private synchronized void disableKeyguard() {
    if (mKeyguardLock == null) {
        mKeyguardLock = mKeyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(Log.LOGTAG);
        mKeyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
    }
}

private synchronized void releaseLocks() {
    AlarmAlertWakeLock.release();
    enableKeyguard();
}

public void reportAlarm(
        int idx, boolean enabled, int hour, int minutes,
        Alarms.DaysOfWeek daysOfWeek, boolean vibrate, String message, String alert,
        int snooze, int duration, int delay, boolean vibrate_only,
        int volume, int crescendo,
        int captcha_snooze, int captcha_dismiss
) {
    mSnooze = snooze;
    mCaptchaSnooze = captcha_snooze;
    mCaptchaDismiss = captcha_dismiss;
    mDuration = duration;

    updateLayout();
}

private void show_captcha(int captcha_type, int which_state)
{
    CaptchaInterface captcha;
    if (captcha_type == Alarms.CAPTCHA_TYPE_PUZZLE) {
        captcha = new PuzzleCaptcha(this);
    }
    else
    if (captcha_type == Alarms.CAPTCHA_TYPE_MATH) {
        captcha = new MathCaptcha(this);
    }
    else
        return;
    if (mCaptchaShown) return;
    mCaptchaShown = true;
    final int which = which_state;
    captcha.setOnCorrectListener(new CaptchaInterface.OnCorrectListener() {
        public void onCorrect() {
            mCaptchaDone = true;
            if (which == SNOOZE) {
                snooze();
            }
            else
            if (which == DISMISS) {
                dismiss();
            }
            finish();
        }
    });
    ((Dialog)captcha).setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            mCaptchaShown = false;
        }
    });
    captcha.show();
}
```

}

Receiver

```
import android.content.Context;
```

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
private final static int STALE_WINDOW = 60 * 30;

@Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(Alarms.ID, 0);
    long setFor = intent.getLongExtra(Alarms.TIME, 0);


    Log.v("AlarmReceiver.onReceive() id " + id + " setFor " + setFor +
            " now " + now);

    if (now > setFor + STALE_WINDOW * 1000) {
        if (Log.LOGV) Log.v("AlarmReceiver ignoring stale alarm intent id"
                + id + " setFor " + setFor + " now " + now);
        return;
    }

    AlarmAlertWakeLock.acquire(context);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
    context.sendBroadcast(i);

            Intent fireAlarm = new Intent(context, AlarmAlert.class);
    fireAlarm.putExtra(Alarms.ID, id);
    fireAlarm.putExtra(Alarms.LABEL, intent.getStringExtra(Alarms.LABEL));
    fireAlarm.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
    context.startActivity(fireAlarm);
}
```

}

помогите разобраться что не так в коде

Comment: ммм... receiver?